# Set Jsf Page Locale according to browser locale

Tags: jsf, browser, locale

I am using Locale browserLocale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale(); to get my browser locale. But it's returning the system default locale, I already changed my browser locale through Settings.